# angular 2 Template parse errors unexpected character EOF

Tags: javascript, angular

I just opened and rerun my angular 2 TS app in visual studio.

Last time I did this it worked without any error I am pretty sure.

Now I get this error in the browser console and the app is not loading completely:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("
   test

</foot[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@22:6
angular2.js:23083 EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("
   test

</foot[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@22:6BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.js:23083
angular2.js:23083 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.js:23083
angular2.js:23083 Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("
   test

</foot[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@22:6
    at new BaseException (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:7351:21)
    at TemplateNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:20019:15)
    at http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:20008:24
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:1243:24)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:13438:32)
    at zoneBoundFn (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:1220:26)
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:468:17)
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:480:18)
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:451:12)
    at http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:123:10

-----async gap-----
Error
    at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:2236:29)
    at Zone.fork (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:2285:47)
    at Zone.bind (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:1218:53)
    at bindArguments (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:1401:36)
    at lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise.obj.(anonymous function) [as then] (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:1413:46)
    at TemplateNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:20007:44)
    at TemplateCompiler.normalizeDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:24233:39)
    at http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:24306:24
    at Array.map (native)
    at Array.map (http://localhost:55555/lib/es6-shim.js:1113:14)

-----async gap-----
Error
    at _getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:2236:29)
    at Zone.fork (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:2285:47)
    at NgZone._createInnerZone (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:13426:39)
    at new NgZone (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:13292:32)
    at createNgZone (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:12475:12)
    at PlatformRef_.application (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:12550:31)
    at Object.bootstrap (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:24805:64)
    at execute (http://localhost:55555/app/main.js:28:23)
    at u (http://localhost:55555/lib/system.js:5:3330)
    at Object.execute (http://localhost:55555/lib/system.js:5:6218)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.js:23083
:55555/app/main.js:31 BaseExceptionmessage: "Template parse errors:↵Unexpected character "EOF" ("↵   test
↵    
↵</foot[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@22:6"stack: "Error: Template parse errors:↵Unexpected character "EOF" ("↵   test
↵    
↵</foot[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@22:6↵    at new BaseException (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:7351:21)↵    at TemplateNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:20019:15)↵    at http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:20008:24↵    at Zone.run (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:1243:24)↵    at Zone.run (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2.js:13438:32)↵    at zoneBoundFn (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:1220:26)↵    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:468:17)↵    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:480:18)↵    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish (http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:451:12)↵    at http://localhost:55555/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:123:10"__proto__: __(anonymous function) @ :55555/app/main.js:31
```

**When I check the AppComponent.ts class**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {FORM_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/common';
import {RouterActive} from './router-active';
import {Schoolyears} from './schoolyears/schoolyear.component';
import {Administration} from './administration/administration.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [...FORM_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterActive],
    pipes: [],
    styles: [],
    templateUrl: './app/app.html'   
})
@RouteConfig([
      { path: '/', component: Schoolyears, name: 'Index' },
        { path: '/schoolyears', component: Schoolyears, name: 'Index' },
        { path: '/administration', component: Administration, name: 'Administration' }

       //{ path: '/', redirectTo: ['Index'] } // otherwise url when not exist
])
export class AppComponent {
     name = 'Angular 2 Webpack Starter';
    url = 'https://twitter.com/AngularClass';
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

**or the app.html**

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
        <ul>
            <li router-active>
                <a [routerLink]="['Index']">Schoolyears</a>
            </li>
            <li router-active>
                <a [routerLink]="['Administration']">Administration</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>

<footer>
   test

</footer>
```

**My main.ts which is the entry poin to everything**

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>

import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap, ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
//import {APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';


const ENV_PROVIDERS = [];
ENV_PROVIDERS.push(ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS);

import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ...ENV_PROVIDERS,
    ...HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ...ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })

])
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I can not see anything wrong.

How can I fix that?

**UPDATE**

In the main.js file I seem to get this error "if" that is the real error...

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any 404 errors? What are your other components like (`Schoolyears`, `Administration`, `RouterActive`)?

Comment: No 404 errors. The RouterActive is from https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter. There is no compile error in Schoolyears/Administration.

Comment: I totally removed the footer, saved and refreshed then it works again!  When I put any html-tag after main-tag I get that same error again, what is that? This is so weird, when I restart my server without any html-tag after the main-tag, then I get errors about the main-tag LOL

Comment: Check your order of imports- I had [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35809109/1876949), and few weeks ago same `Unexpected character "EOF"` that turned out to be caused by the same thing... Really hard to debug /;

Comment: I have 7 imports in app.component.ts. That are 128 different orders ;-) As you said it just worked one time then again not...

Comment: Don't try all permutations :P Move `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` above components that are using `map()`.. something like that.

Comment: Exactly that one I moved as it is used by Administration/SchoolyearsService, but no luck.

Comment: I updated my post with a screenshot, but I do not think that is the real error.

Comment: I am starting over with the angular 2 sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview and see how it works ;-)

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the app.html file. Could you provide its content? Thanks!

Comment: But its there... at the top.

Answer (score 8):

This error is tricky, since the error message is often misleading. The error will show one of your last lines of HTML; however, don't search for the issue there! This is simply the case because a tag was not closed properly beforehand.

This error is fixed by closing a tag which is missing its closing tag. Sometimes, like in my case of `<textarea>`, this is tricky to catch because Angular is satisfied if `<input>` is unclosed; however, `<textarea>` **must be closed.**

If you're wondering which HTML element tags must be closed, simply search for `tag omission` in regards to the specific element you're curious about.

**Consider running your HTML through a linter in order to quickly catch these errors!**

---

#### Code example of my situation

In my case, I was not closing one of my `<textarea>` elements.

Previously my code was as follows

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label for="example" class="form-label">Example</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="example" formControlName="example" lines="2">
</div>
```

To fix this issue, I simply closed the `<textarea>` element, as follows

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label for="example" class="form-label">Example</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="example" formControlName="example" lines="2"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man,I wasted my day for this error

Answer (score 6):

I got the Unexpected character "EOF" error , pretty hard to debug , what i did to solve the problem :

There was an html comment in my component's template file :
    `<!----- Notifications ----->`
i changed it to :
    `<!-- Notifications -->`
and it wasn't the first time , every time i have this error i fix html comments to start with `<!--` and finish with `-->` and not `--->`, and the problem is solved.

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/The_Importance_of_Correct_HTML_Commenting

In my case it was comments , but i think that in general you need to have valid html, or the parser could throw that error.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed you get it when HTML is invalid in Angular2 app. So, try to debug by elimination, unusual html tags etc.. In my case, I was missing  closing.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to some incompatibility between a2 and webpack html-loader. A workaround as used in [official a2 webpack guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) is

```
  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },
```

More about this can be found in [issue 7295](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7295)